# graphql query on client with different version of API

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I'm building a Typescript client that should be able to talk to multiple version of an API.

For example, there is a type `User` and there are 2 version: v0.1 and v0.2. In version v0.2 there is a new field on the `User` type called `address`.

As a a client of the API, I want to query the `User` type, but use the same query to talk to both version of the API. What I expect is that API v0.1 will return null for this new property.

Is there a way to do this? At the moment I getting this error:

```
GraphQL error: Field 'address' doesn't exist on type 'User'
```

If it's not possible, does that mean that for every change to the API, if a client would like to be backward compatible, it needs to store different schema for each version?